# An elementary counting question

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Say we have an alphabet of size $N$, how many different strings of length ($M\ge N$) can be formed, with the requirement that every element in the alphabet must be used at least once?

For example, in binary case ($N=2$) and $M=3$, the result should be 6: {001,010,100,011,101,110}.

I've tried several ways including the most straightforward one: all possible strings - missing 1 element - missing 2 elements - ... - missing $N-1$ elements:

$$N^M-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{N \choose n}(N-n)^M$$

But I have difficulty in deriving a succinct and computable formula for large N and M, say $N=90, M=150$.

Comment: What attempts have you made ?.

Comment: Please read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664726/how-many-strings-contain-every-letter-of-the-alphabet) to get ideas on how to solve your problem. This problem is actually solved there using Stirling numbers of the second kind as well as the inclusion-exclusion which you have allueded to.

Comment: You are subtracting too much.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a neat and tidy closed form (there is a big messy one, but who wants to find that?).

---

There are $M^N$ possible words of length $M$, but we wish to eliminate those where not all of the $N$ symbols occur.   Using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P_{M,N} & = N^M - N (N-1)^M+ \tbinom{N}{2}(N-2)^M - \cdots \\[1ex] & = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-1)^{k}\binom{N}{k} (N-k)^M \\[1ex] & = N! \begin{Bmatrix}M\\N\end{Bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Where $\begin{Bmatrix}M\\N\end{Bmatrix}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html).  Also written $S_M^{(N)}$

---

$\therefore \mathsf P_{150,90} =$ ${1 371 888 226 882 746 223 040
\\ 915 149 547 378 647 262 473 014 145 149
\\ 246 945 588 611 955 359 496 306 821 323
\\ 034 349 470 752 415 031 431 297 444 805
\\ 751 630 899 722 405 090 970 396 500 796
\\ 345 791 421 010 196 633 004 533 551 096
\\ 046 338 094 118 112 171 870 375 289 231
\\ 669 513 854 201 486 890 501 879 055 994 
\\ 428 345 511 994 557 372 853 346 262 083 
\\ 971 317 760 000 000 000 000 000 000 000}$