# Number of pairs of distinct strings with length $L$ and $K$ distinct characters

Tags: combinatorics

Two strings $S$ and $T$ are *similar* if we can rename the same letters in $S$ and thus get $T$. For example, $abacaba$ and $xyxzxyx$ are similar, whereas $abacaba$ and $pqpqpqp$ are not.

Given $L$ and $K$, count the number of pairs of distinct strings each of which has length $L$ and consists of $K$ distinct letters such that two strings in each pair are similar. We can assume that the alphabet consists of a-zA-z i.e 52 possible characters.

Actually, this is a problem from a programming contest (it's over now so we can safely discuss the problems). Nevertheless, I believe this is just combinatorics. I am a bit stuck. There is an example of what the algorithm should output: $(5,2) \to 15$. I can't quite understand how that could be such a small number since there are at least $\binom{52}{k}$ ways to choose those $k$ distinct numbers.

Is there anything I am missing in the problem statement?

Comment: From $2$ characters you can make $2^5-2=30$ different surjective (i.e.,  using both characters) strings of length $5$. If you are allowed to interchange the characters you arrive at $15$ types of strings. – Maybe you should make available the original formulation of the problem.

Comment: Actually, this is already the original formulation of the problem. In the general case, would it be correct to say that this simply the Stirling numbers of the second kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding in the problem statement. They're only considering an alphabet of size $K$, not 52. The factor arising from choosing the substitution from 52 allowed characters will, as you noted, be enormous. But they're not considering it.

I'll start by answering the question as stated:

---

Let $N(L, K)$ be the number of distinct strings of length $L$ made of **given** $K$ characters (or $K$ generic placeholder characters), with each character used at least once, for $L\geq K$.

$$N(L, K) = K^L - {K\choose 1}(K-1)^L + {K\choose 2}(K-2)^L\dots = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{K-1} (-1)^i {K \choose i}(K-i)^L$$
This uses the inclusion-exclusion principle. Check this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/664790/52735

---

From $N(L, K)$, we can remove the similar strings by dividing by $K!$ (number of permutations of $K$ letters).

Each remaining string of length $L$ with $K$ generic characters can be turned into a real string by choosing an appropriate substitution from the 52 possible letters. Two such assignments will give *similar* strings.

Putting these together:

$$\mathrm{ExpectedAns}(L, K) = \frac{N(L, K)}{K!} \times \frac{^{52}\mathrm{P}_{K} \times (^{52}\mathrm{P}_K-1)}{2}$$
with $N(L, K)$ given above (for $L\geq K$). This clearly doesn't match $\mathrm{Ans}(5, 2) = 15$.

---

My guess is they're only allowing for $K$ given characters to be substituted. So maybe this is what they're looking for

$$\mathrm{Ans}(N, K) = \frac{N(L, K)}{K!} \times \frac{^{K}\mathrm{P}_{K} \times (^{K}\mathrm{P}_K-1)}{2}$$
$$\mathrm{Ans}(N, K) = \frac{N(L, K)}{K!} \times \frac{K! \times (K!-1)}{2}$$
For $(5, 2)$ this gives $15$. The factor $N(L, K)/K!$ is referred to as Stirling numbers of the second kind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Answer (score 0):

If a string of length $L$ has $K$ distinct characters, the remaining $L-K$ characters would be repeated characters. Note that the question would not make sense when $L \lt K$. So, $L \ge K$.

In short, one method is to consider all possible ways in which the characters could be distributed, find the number of permutations in each case, and add them up to get the number of all possible permutations of the string in question.

Since the string would necessarily have $K$ distinct characters, let's look at all possible ways in which we can fill up the remaining $L-K$ spaces with the same $K$ characters. The string, finally, would contain at least $1$ occurrence of each of the $K$ distinct characters.

Let $k_i$ be the number of occurrences of the $i^{th}$ character from the set of all distinct characters, where $\sum_{i=1}^K k_i = L$ and $k_i \ge 1$. Then, the number of permutations of the string in this specific case would be $$\frac{L!}{\prod_{i=1}^K k_i!}.$$

These are coefficients of terms in the multinomial expansion of $(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_K)^L$. Specifically, they are coefficients of terms in which no variable has a power of $0$, as $k_i \ge 1$.

In order to get the sum of all such coefficients, we subtract the sum of all coefficients whose terms have at least one of the variable powers as $0$ from the total sum of all coefficients in the expansion.

The total sum of all coefficients is obtained by setting every variable to $1$ in $(x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_K)^L$, and is equal to $K^L$. Similarly, the sum of all coefficients of terms where a certain set of variables have power $0$ is obtained by setting that exact set of variables to $0$ and the rest to $1$. Note that every such variable combination has to be covered.

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle, the coefficient sum we want is obtained as $$K^L + \sum_{i=1}^{K-1} (-1)^{i}{K \choose i}(K-i)^L.$$

This is the number of all distinct permutations of the string under the given constraints. But this is not the answer we need.

In order to obtain that, we must consider the number of ways in which the set of all distinct characters can be mapped to itself, generating a permutation on that set. This is so that we know how many times the same sequence repeats with the characters merely renamed to some other (or even the same) characters from the same set. The number of permutations possible on the character set is $K!$. The number of distinct permutations of the string would thus contain $K!$ permutations for each sequence that is unique up to similarity.

The required number is, therefore, $$\frac{K^L + \sum_{i=1}^{K-1} (-1)^{i}{K \choose i}(K-i)^L}{K!}.$$

Comment: To get the number of **pairs** of similar strings, the final expression will need to multiplied by K! * (K!-1) / 2, I think. From each string (unique up to similarity), we can build a set of K! mutually similar strings.

Comment: Cool, but why is it K! * (K! - 1) / 2? Each unique string can be renamed in K! ways, generating K! / 2 pairs. So shouldn't the factor just be K! / 2?

Comment: From a set of N elements, there are (N C 2) = N(N-1)/2 ways of picking pairs of elements, hence the K!*(K!-1)/2 factor. K!/2 would be the number of non-overlapping pairs

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thanks!